# If everything is an object in Python, are variables objects too?

Tags: python

From 'Introduction to Computer Science Using Python' by Charles Dierbach :

> Local variables are automatically created (allocated memory) when a function is called, and destroyed (deallocated) when the function terminates.

I think of variables in Python as name or an identifier pointing at an object. So if they're being allocated memory either they're supposed to be objects as well or they can be allocated memory without being objects?

Comment: Your understanding seems more correct than the quote you included.

Comment: "Local variables are automatically created (allocated memory) when a function is called, and destroyed (deallocated) when the function terminates." This is simply wrong. And no, variables are not objects in Python. Of course, in global scopes there might actually be a `str` object in a `dict` object and that is the name and namespace. But variables shouldn't be thought of as objects, they are names that refer to objects in particular namespaces.

Comment: Wow. Perhaps that passage is clarified in context, but alone, it does not recommend that book well.

Comment: This to me seems like a classic "I'm just going to write a textbook on Python and assume it works the same as C++/Java that I taught for years so I'm going to throw in a bunch of misleading and false information". Unfortunately, it's very common as curriculums have switched over to Python.

Comment: @CrazyChucky the book was pretty consistent so far, until this.

Comment: @dexter it might be an fine computer science textbook, just take it's claims about the Python programming language with a grain of salt.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the entire statement is "The period of time that a variable exists is called its lifetime. Local variables are automatically created (allocated memory) when a function is called, and destroyed (deallocated) when the function terminates. Thus, the lifetime of a local variable is equal to the duration of its function's execution. Consequently, the values of local variables are not retained from one function call to the next" . Is there a scope of correction in this statement and what will be the technically correct way to explain the same?

Comment: The problem is that it is talking about variables as if Python variables were like C variables. They aren't. Here's a great post on the two different concepts of "variable" in these langauges: http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/  In Python, *variables aren't allocated/deallocated* because *variabels* aren't chunks of memory (ok, so a pointer is allocated somewhere at some point, but how and when that would happen is an implementation detail. In current versions, those pointers exist when the *code object is compiled* and not related to when the function is called)

Comment: And a lot of professors / educators who taught langauges like C for decades just can't let go of this mental model and don't bother to update it with a very different langauge like Python  -- the problem is that a bunch of other langaues now have that same model Java (really!), Javascript, Ruby, etc, basically, any widely-used interpreted OOP language (which were pretty popular in the last couple decades).

Comment: But in any case, in Python, variables do have lifetimes, but this not intimately related with memory allocation/deallocation. Local namespaces are optimized symbol tables (basically, arrays of pointers) that get created when the function is defined. Global / object namespaces are (usually) just `dict` objects. The "lifetime" of a local variable is conceptual, it is how long it counts as referencing the object it references (for a function call, that "lifetime" only lasts for the execution of the function). All objects are allocated on a privately managed heap and memory management is automatic

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: although the question here is rather brief for Stack Overflow, it nevertheless has produced some interesting insights in the comments. Is it worth recording some of that in an answer? The relationship between variable scope and the memory operations that are performed on them sounds like it is worth saving.

Answer (score 0):

No, variables are not objects in Python.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).